# いろいろ考えてみると、ふだんは田舎の自然を楽しみ、時には町の楽しみも味わうという生活が理想的なのではないだろうか

Tags: grammar, meaning, parsing

I have problems with Sentence 3, Exercise 7 [here](https://www.docdroid.net/IRZXxk4/img-20170809-0002-new.pdf):

> いろいろ考えてみると、ふだんは田舎の自然を楽しみ、時には町の楽しみも味わうという生活が理想的なのではないだろうか。

I filled in the gaps as the accompanying solutions manual suggested it. Here’s my attempt at translation:

> When you try to think about it (=these various things?), don’t you
> think that in the normal case one enjoys the homelands nature, and at
> times the life, which is the towns pleasure and taste, are not ideal.

It definitely feels like something is off. いろいろ in the first part seems to be in adverbial use, but I can’t figure out how to translate it in a meaningful way. I have no idea about ふだんは; same goes for 時には. The worst thing is 楽しみも味わうという生活. も seems to indicate that たのしみ is a noun here, but あじわう definitely is a verb. In the end, the connection of the two words isn’t transparent to me.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you're having difficulty stitching the parts together.

I'd translate the parts of the sentence as follows:

> ふだんは田舎の自然を楽しむ
> to usually get to enjoy the nature of the countryside
>
> 時には町の楽しみも味わう
> to occasionally get to appreciate even the joys of [being in] a town
>
> ...という生活が理想的だ
> A life [consisting] of ... is ideal.

I'd take some liberty in translating the opening phrase

> いろいろ考えてみると
> If you think about it a bit....

And for the closing portion of the sentence:

> ...ではないだろうか
> wouldn't it be ....

In this sentence, ふだんは and 時には contrast with one another.  So, the speaker is saying that **usually** they wish to enjoy the countryside but **occasionally** get to spend time in a town (or city).

Putting it all together gives you:

> If you think about it a bit, wouldn't it be the ideal life to generally enjoy the nature of the countryside and occasionally get to taste even the pleasures of city [life].

One point of possible confusion is how 楽しみ is being used.  The first instance of 楽しみ is the continuative form of 楽しむ (to enjoy); the second instance is 楽しみ as a noun (joy, pleasure, delights).

The continuative form lets you know that this is just the first part of a multiple part idea being expressed,

> "to enjoy *something* and ... [another verb] ...".

In this particular sentence,

> "to enjoy *something* and taste *something else*.